# Fix Buffer Overflow Exploit on Web Server

Tags: c, webserver

I have a buffer overflow vulnerability in a simple webserver. It can be exploited with a http GET request. I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix it. My guess is that it has to do with: `char hdrval[1024];` but I could be wrong. Can anyone else see whats wrong?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

typedef struct {
  char *method;
  char *uri;
  char *version;
  char *headers;
} httpreq_t;


/* NOTE: this function is based on a function provided in the GNU "timegm" man
   page. timegm is a GNU extension to time.h that returns the given tm struct as
   a UNIX timestamp in GMT/UTC, rather than local time. The man page suggests a
   function similar to the one below as a portable equivalent.
*/
time_t my_timegm(struct tm *tm) {
  time_t ret;
  char *tz;

  tz = getenv("TZ");
  putenv("TZ=GMT");
  tzset();
  ret = mktime(tm);
  if (tz) {
    char envstr[strlen(tz) + 4];
    envstr[0] = '\0';
    strcat(envstr, "TZ=");
    strcat(envstr, tz);
    putenv(envstr);
  } else {
    putenv("TZ=");
  }

  tzset();

  return ret;
}

char *get_header(const httpreq_t *req, const char* headername) {
  char *hdrptr;
  char *hdrend;
  char *retval = NULL;

  char searchstr[strlen(headername) + 5];
  strcpy(searchstr, "\r\n");
  strcat(searchstr, headername);
  strcat(searchstr, ": ");

  if (hdrptr = strstr(req->headers, searchstr)) { 
    hdrptr += strlen(searchstr); 
    if (hdrend = strstr(hdrptr, "\r\n")) { 
            char hdrval[1024]; // temporary return value
            memcpy((char *)hdrval, hdrptr, (hdrend - hdrptr));
            hdrval[hdrend - hdrptr] = '\0'; // tack null onto end of header value
            int hdrvallen = strlen(hdrval);
        retval = (char *)malloc((hdrvallen + 1) * sizeof(char)); // malloc a space for retval
      strcpy(retval, (char *)hdrval);
    } else {
      retval = (char *)malloc((strlen(hdrptr) + 1) * sizeof(char)); //
      strcpy(retval, hdrptr);
    }
  }

  return retval;
}

/* As long as str begins with a proper HTTP-Version followed by delim, returns a
   pointer to the start of the version number (e.g., 1.0). Returns NULL otherwise.
*/
char *http_version_str(char *str, char *delim) {
  char *vstart = strstr(str, "HTTP/");
  char *vnumstart = str + 5;
  char *vdot = strchr(str, '.');
  char *vend = strstr(str, delim);
  char *digits = "0123456789";
  int majvlen = 0;
  int minvlen = 0;

  if (!vstart || !vdot // something's missing
      || vstart != str) // str doesn't start with "HTTP/"
    return NULL;

  majvlen = strspn(vnumstart, digits);
  minvlen = strspn(vdot + 1, digits);

  if (majvlen < 1 || (vnumstart + majvlen) != vdot // bad major version
      || minvlen < 1 || (vdot + minvlen + 1) != vend) // bad minor version
    return NULL;

  return vnumstart;
}

/* Fills req with the request data from datastr. Returns 0 on success.
 */

int parsereq(httpreq_t *req, char *datastr) {
  char *position;
  char *last_position = datastr;
  char *temp_position;
  int matchlen;

  req->method = "";
  req->uri = "";
  req->version = "";
  req->headers = "";

  if (!(position = strchr(last_position, ' '))) {
    return 1;
  }
  matchlen = (int)(position - last_position);
  req->method = (char *)malloc((matchlen + 1) * sizeof(char));
  memcpy(req->method, last_position, matchlen);
  req->method[matchlen] = '\0';
  last_position = position + 1;

  if (!(position = strchr(last_position, ' '))
      && !(position = strstr(last_position, "\r\n"))) {
    return 1;
  }

  // strip any query string out of the URI
  if ((temp_position = strchr(last_position, '?')) && temp_position < position)
    matchlen = (int)(temp_position - last_position);
  else
    matchlen = (int)(position - last_position);

  req->uri = (char *)malloc((matchlen + 1) * sizeof(char));
  memcpy(req->uri, last_position, matchlen);
  req->uri[matchlen] = '\0';
  if (position[0] == '\r') {
    req->version = "0.9";
    req->headers = "";
    return 0; // simple req -- uri only
  }

  // If we get here, it's a full request, get the HTTP version and headers
  last_position = position + 1;

  if (!(position = strstr(last_position, "\r\n"))
      || !(last_position = http_version_str(last_position, "\r\n"))) {
    return 1;
  }

  matchlen = (int)(position - last_position);
  req->version = (char *)malloc((matchlen + 1) * sizeof(char));
  memcpy(req->version, last_position, matchlen);
  req->version[matchlen] = '\0';
  last_position = position;

  req->headers = (char *)malloc(strlen(last_position) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(req->headers, last_position);

  return 0;
} 

char *contype(char *ext) {
  if (strcmp(ext, "html") == 0) return "text/html";
  else if (strcmp(ext, "htm") == 0) return "text/html";
  else if (strcmp(ext, "jpeg") == 0) return "image/jpeg";
  else if (strcmp(ext, "jpg") == 0) return "image/jpeg";
  else if (strcmp(ext, "gif") == 0) return "image/gif";
  else if (strcmp(ext, "txt") == 0) return "text/plain";
  else return "application/octet-stream";

}

char *status(int statcode) {
  if (statcode == 200)  return "200 OK";
  else if (statcode == 304) return "304 Not Modified";
  else if (statcode == 400) return "400 Bad Request";
  else if (statcode == 403) return "403 Forbidden";
  else if (statcode == 404) return "404 Not Found";
  else if (statcode == 500) return "500 Internal Server Error";
  else if (statcode == 501) return "501 Not Implemented";
  else return "";
}

int send_response(int sockfd, httpreq_t *req, int statcode) {
  int urifd;
  const int BUFSIZE = 1024;
  char sendmessage[BUFSIZE];
  char *path = req->uri;

  if (req->uri == NULL || req->method == NULL || 
      req->headers == NULL || req->version == NULL) {
      return 0;
  }


  if ((path[0] == '/') || ((strstr(path, "http://") == path)
               && (path = strchr(path + 7,  '/')))) {
    path += 1; // remove leading slash
    if (path[0] == '\0') {  // substituting in index.html for a blank URL!
      path = "index.html";
    } else if (path[strlen(path) - 1] == '/') {
      //concatenating index.html for a /-terminated URL!
      strcat(path, "index.html");    
    }
  } else {
    statcode = 400;
  }

  if (statcode == 200 && (urifd = open(path, O_RDONLY, 0)) < 0) {
    if (errno == ENOENT || errno == ENOTDIR) { // file or directory doesn't exist
      statcode = 404;
    } else if (errno == EACCES) { // access denied
      statcode = 403;
    } else {
      // some other file access problem
      statcode = 500;
    }
  }

  if (strstr(path, "..") != NULL) {
        statcode = 500;
  }


  sendmessage[0] = '\0';
  if (strcmp(req->version, "0.9") != 0) { // full request
    char *ext; // file extension
    time_t curtime;
    char *imstime;
    struct tm tm;
    struct stat stbuf;


    if (statcode == 200) {
      if (ext = strrchr(path, '.')) ext++; // skip the '.'
      else ext = "";
    } else {
      // errors are always html messages
      ext = "html";
    }

    // Conditional GET
    if ((strcmp(req->method, "GET") == 0)
    && (statcode == 200)
    && (imstime = get_header(req, "If-Modified-Since"))) {

      // Get statistics about the requested URI from the local filesystem
      if (stat(path, &stbuf) == -1) {
    statcode = 500;
      }

      if (!strptime(imstime, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", &tm)
      && !strptime(imstime, "%a, %d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S GMT", &tm)
      && !strptime(imstime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", &tm)) {
    // badly formatted date
    statcode = 400;
      }

      if (stbuf.st_mtime <= my_timegm(&tm)) {
    // Not Modified
    statcode = 304;
      }
    }

    time(&curtime); // time for Date: header
    strcat(sendmessage, "HTTP/1.0 ");
    strcat(sendmessage, status(statcode));    
    strcat(sendmessage, "\r\nDate: ");
    strncat(sendmessage, asctime(gmtime(&curtime)), 24);
    strcat(sendmessage, "\r\nServer: Frobozz Magic Software Company Webserver v.002");
    strcat(sendmessage, "\r\nConnection: close");
    strcat(sendmessage, "\r\nContent-Type: ");    
    strcat(sendmessage, contype(ext));
    strcat(sendmessage, "\r\n\r\n");

  }

  if (statcode != 200) {
    strcat(sendmessage, "<html><head><title>");
    strcat(sendmessage, status(statcode));
    strcat(sendmessage, "</title></head><body><h2>HTTP/1.0</h2><h1>");
    strcat(sendmessage, status(statcode));
    strcat(sendmessage, "</h1><h2>URI: ");
    strcat(sendmessage, path);
    strcat(sendmessage, "</h2></body></html>");
  }

  if (sendmessage[0] != '\0') {
    // send headers as long as there are headers to send
    if (send(sockfd, sendmessage, strlen(sendmessage), 0) < 0) {
      perror("send");
      pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
  }

  if (statcode == 200 && (strcmp(req->method, "HEAD") != 0)) {
    // send the requested file as long as there's no error and the
    // request wasn't just for the headers
    int readbytes;

    while (readbytes = read(urifd, sendmessage, BUFSIZE)) {
      if (readbytes < 0) {
    perror("read");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
      }
      if (send(sockfd, sendmessage, readbytes, 0) < 0) {
    perror("send");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
      }
    }
  }
}

void *data_thread(void *sockfd_ptr) {
  int sockfd = *(int *) sockfd_ptr;
  const int BUFSIZE = 5;
  char recvmessage[BUFSIZE];
  char *headerstr = NULL;
  char *newheaderstr = NULL;
  int recvbytes = 0;
  int curheadlen = 0;
  int totalheadlen = 0;
  httpreq_t req;
  int statcode = 200;
  int done = 0;
  int seen_header = 0;
  char *header_end;
  int content_length = 0;
  char *qstr;

  free(sockfd_ptr); // we have the int value out of this now
  recvmessage[BUFSIZE - 1] = '\0'; // mark end of "string"


  /* Read incoming client message from the socket */  
  while(!done && (recvbytes = recv(sockfd, recvmessage, BUFSIZE - 1, 0))) {
    if (recvbytes < 0) {
      perror("recv");
      pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    recvmessage[recvbytes] = '\0';

    if (seen_header) {
      // getting the entity body
      content_length -= recvbytes;
      if (content_length <= 0) done = 1;

    } else {            
      newheaderstr = (char *) malloc((totalheadlen + recvbytes + 1) * sizeof(char));
      newheaderstr[totalheadlen + recvbytes] = '\0';
      memcpy(newheaderstr, headerstr, totalheadlen);
      memcpy(newheaderstr + totalheadlen, recvmessage, recvbytes);
      if (headerstr) free(headerstr);
      headerstr = newheaderstr;
      totalheadlen += recvbytes;

      header_end = strstr(headerstr, "\r\n\r\n");

      if (header_end) {
    seen_header = 1;
    header_end[2] = '\0';

    if (parsereq(&req, headerstr) != 0) {
      statcode = 400;
    }

    if (strcmp(req.method, "POST") == 0) {
      // grab the body length
      char *clenstr = get_header(&req, "Content-Length");

      if (clenstr) {
        content_length = atoi(clenstr) - ((headerstr + totalheadlen) - header_end - 4);
        if (content_length <= 0) done = 1;
        free(clenstr);

      } else {
        statcode = 400; // bad request -- no content length
        done = 1;
      }

    } else {
      // This isn't a POST, so there's no entity body
      done = 1;

      if (strcmp(req.method, "GET") != 0
          && strcmp(req.method, "HEAD") != 0) {
        statcode = 501; // unknown request method
      }
    }
      }
    }
  } // end of recv while loop

    // used to deref a NULL pointer here... :(
    if (headerstr != NULL) {
          printf("%s\n", headerstr);
          free(headerstr);

    }

    send_response(sockfd, &req, statcode);
    close(sockfd);


  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int acc, sockfd, clen, port;
  struct hostent *he;
  struct sockaddr_in caddr, saddr;

  if(argc <= 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "No port specified. Exiting!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  port = atoi(argv[1]);

  /* Obtain name and address for the local host */
  if((he=gethostbyname("localhost"))==NULL) {
    herror("gethostbyname");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Open a TCP (Internet Stream) socket */
  if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Create socket address structure for the local host */
  memset((char *) &saddr, '\0', sizeof(saddr));
  saddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  saddr.sin_port=htons(port);
  saddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  /* Bind our local address so that the client can send to us */
  if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &saddr,sizeof(saddr)) == -1) {  
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
  }

  if(listen(sockfd,5) < 0) {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Infinite loop for receiving and processing client requests */
  for(;;) {
    clen=sizeof(caddr);

    /* Wait for a connection for a client process */
    acc=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &caddr,(socklen_t*)&clen);
    if(acc < 0) {
      perror("accept");
      exit(1);
    } else {
      pthread_t *thread = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
      int *sockfd_ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));

      *sockfd_ptr = acc;
      pthread_create(thread, NULL, data_thread, sockfd_ptr);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a request that exploits it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could have a bound check before copying to the buffer?

For example, add

```
if(hdrend - hdrptr >= 1024)
    exit(1)
```

before

```
memcpy((char *)hdrval, hdrptr, (hdrend - hdrptr));
```

Answer (score 0):

The segfault happens at the point below.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    [Switching to Thread 0xb7ff4b70 (LWP 3902)]
        Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    [Switching to Thread 0xb7ff4b70 (LWP 3902)]
    0x08049507 in send_response (sockfd=6, req=0xb7ff4340, statcode=200)
        at server/webserver.c:219
    warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
    219   if (req->uri == NULL || req->method == NULL ||
```

The memory address is

```
(gdb) p $_siginfo._sifields._sigfault.si_addr
$3 = (void *) 0x69cb120
```

The code that needs to be rewritten is

```
214   int urifd;
215   const int BUFSIZE = 1024;
216   char sendmessage[BUFSIZE];
217   char *path = req->uri;
218   
219   if (req->uri == NULL || req->method == NULL || 
220       req->headers == NULL || req->version == NULL) {
221       return 0;
```

Comment: How would you exploit this vulnerability just by sending a request with a URI longer than 1025 bytes? Could you fix it just by putting an if statement that checks to make sure req->uri is less than 1024 bytes?